# How to split a string with a certain character without considering the length of the character?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work on this string

```
    abc
    def
    --------------
    efg
    hij    
    ------
    xyz
    pqr
    --------------
```

Now I have to split the string with the `-` character.
So far I'm first spliting the string in lines and then finding the occurrence of `-`  and the replacing the line with a single *, then combining the whole string and splitting them again.

I'm trying to get the data as

```
string[] set = 
{
    "abc 
    def",
    "efg
    hij",
    "xyz
    pqr"
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: In this example "abcdef" treated as a single string or two separate strings?

Comment: single string on different lines tho.

Comment: `String.Split` does exactly that.. Not really sure what you even tried.

Comment: Probably we need some more context here. What do you mean by different lines, for display purpose?

Comment: The input string specify different entries by `----------------`.
Now the number of `-` was not fixed to an entry. One user might just put `-----` some other just `---`. I wanted to split the values no matter the number of `-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var spitStrings = yourString.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If i understand your question, this above code solves it.

Comment: You win this round.

Comment: And I'm sorry for lack of explanation. Well, consider that an advantage now! :)

Comment: first means nothing, its the answer that counts. Can't believe we are fighting over reps

Comment: @HishamMaudarbocus Let's hug it out? /hug

Comment: big hug bro, big hug /hug

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused with exactly what you're asking, but won't this work?

```
string[] seta = 
{
    "abc\ndef",
    "efg\nhij",
    "xyz\npqr"
}
```

`\n = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix`

`\r = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS`

`\n\r = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows`

`(char)13 = \n = CR // Same as \n`

If I'm understanding your question about splitting `-`'s then the following should work.

```
string s = "abc-def-efg-hij-xyz-pqr"; // example?
string[] letters = s.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

If this is what your array looks like at the moment, then you can loop through it as follows:

```
string[] seta = {
    "abc-def",
    "efg-hij",
    "xyz-pqr"
};

foreach (var letter in seta)
{
    string[] letters = letter.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    // do something with letters?
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to split the string with `-------`. No matter the number of `-`

Answer (score 1):

Use of string split function using the specific char or string of chars (here -) can be used. 
The output will be array of strings. Then choose whichever strings you want.
Example:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this below code will help you...

```
    string m = "adasd------asdasd---asdasdsad-------asdasd------adsadasd---asdasd---asdadadad-asdadsa-asdada-s---adadasd-adsd";
    var array = m.Split('-');

    List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();

    if (array.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string item in array)
        {
            if (item != "")
            {
                myCollection.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

    string[] str = myCollection.ToArray();
```

if it does then don't forget to mark my answer thanks....;)

Answer (score 0):

```
string set = "abc----def----------------efg----hij--xyz-------pqr" ;
var spitStrings = set.Split(new char[]{'-'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

EDIT -

He wants to split the strings no matter how many '-' are there.

```
var spitStrings = set.Split(new char[]{'-'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

This will do the work.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?